# Search option in slicer dropdown in power bi

Tags: powerbi, bar-chart

I drag slicer in sheet and in that i add date field now here i am looking for search bar in dropdown but unable to find it .. where as in second image i add slicer in sheet and i add field month in slicer when i click on 3 dots i found search bar this is what i want in date dropdown but did not get it ..

check below image 
[image]

this is the link of file

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ur5jwh1tk748moy/test_model_2.pbix?dl=0

Comment: Please explain in detail... what exactly you want?

Comment: i want to search bar on dropdown..

Comment: search bar display when i add month field and hide when i add date field.. why ?

Comment: the sample you Provided is NOt Valid PBIX file. Just Check it. Its Composite Model Pbix File.

Comment: @Mr.Bhosale kindly download it ..

Comment: @Rex5 kindly check update..

Comment: kindly first download the file and then open it.. i am able to open it

Comment: @MIRROR I believe the search option can only be performed on text fields. You can enable the 'New Filter Experience' and you will have much more flexibility with date filtering

Answer (score 1):

We have the Search option in the (...) menu section of the slicer, but in case if you have any other version of power bi, then you can just dropdown the list in slicer and press (ctrl+F) to bring the search bar. But the thing is that search bar will disappear after you close the slicer .I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I got your Question.

In the January 2017 release, it looks like the Search facility on a slicer that is set to a drop-down (with Date) has been removed.
And **PowerBI** currently only supports search on string fields. **PowerBI** are not supporting it on a **date** field.

[Check community](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Issues/Search-on-a-slicer-set-as-dropdown/idi-p/115200)

Comment: i see.. u mean search field only visible for text / string data types ?